# Mapping torus of a homotopy equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

The mapping torus $M_f$ of a homeomorphism $f$ of some topological space $X$ is a fiber bundle whose base is a circle and whose fiber is the original space $X$. If instead of a homeomorphism $f$ is just a homotopy equivalence of $X$, is $M_f$ a fibration over the circle with fiber homotopic to $X$?

Answer (score 9):

There's no reason to expect $M_f$ to be a fiber bundle, or even a Hurewicz or Serre fibration. (Think of $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=0$.  This is a homotopy equivalence, but $M_f$ is certainly not locally trivial, nor does $M_f \to S^1$ have any nice lifting properties.)

What *is* true is that the *homotopy fiber* of $M_f\to S^1$ is weakly equivalent to $X$, if $f$ is a homotopy equivalence (or even a weak equivalence).  This often gets proved by using the theory of "quasi-fibrations".

Answer (score 6):

Check out

Homotopy equivalences and mapping torus projections
    D. S. Coram, P. F. Duvall
    Fund. Math. 109 (1980), 1-7

http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm109/fm10911.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is closely related to [a question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2665/is-a-map-that-is-locally-fiberwise-equivalent-to-a-product-a-hurewicz-fibration), which was motivated by wondering whether the mapping cylinder of a homotopy equivalence is a fibration over an interval.  The counterexample given there (for the homotopy equivalence from I to a point) also gives a counterexample for the mapping torus, and makes it easy to see how it goes wrong.